# React Star Rating how to disable after clicking once

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I use the following Code for my  Component and I want to know, how can I disable it, when the user clicked it once.

```
const Rating = ({ stars, clickHandler }) => {
const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
return (
    <>
        <div className="star-rating">
            {[...Array(5)].map((stern, nummer) => {
                nummer += 1;
                return (
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        key={nummer}
                        className={nummer <= rating ? "on" : "off"}
                        onClick={() => setRating(nummer)}>
                        <span className="star">&#9733;</span>
                    </button>

                );
            })}

        </div>
        <p className="starnone">{stars = rating}</p>
        {clickHandler(stars)}
    </>
);

}
```

The click handler is for printing out the clicked value in the console.

Comment: `Array(5)` produces an array with five empty places. Consider using `Array.from({ length: 5 }, (el, i) => i)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use disable when the rating has value > 0

```
<button disable={rating > 0} />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 onClick={() => rating==0 && setRating(nummer)}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the `undefined` as the initial value of your `rating` state, and decide by the state value, e.g:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(undefined);

const rattingIsDisabled = state ? true : false;

....some code
<button disabled={rattingIsDisabled} ....
```

HINT: you don't need to increment your array index.